# Can I programmatically unlink a linked account on Actions on Google?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I've successfully performed account linking. There is a requirement where, if the user fails to provide a slot properly with the correct value, it should require them to re-link their account.

Is there a way to programmatically unlink an already linked account?

Comment: With account linking, you should have an access token that you gave to the user for the Google Assistant. Can you not revoke the access token and deny future requests?

Comment: Yeah. This was the solution I am coming up with now where we expose a Rest API which communicates to keycloak to revoke a token. Was wondering whether there was a built in way to do that for googlee

Comment: There is no programmatic way. Users can unlink manually in the settings.